# OpenShift: Rails (spree) not starting

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree, openshift

I'm trying to host a rails app (spree) in OpenShift. When I make a commit to OpenShift repo, the precompile asset ates forever, and when i try to hit the application it returns error page.

The ruby cartridge log shows the following error

/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-3.0.17/helper-scripts/prespawn:105:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Tried changing the thor version to 0.15.4 as suggested in openshift forum, and also another tried solution suggested in 
https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/rails-passenger-connection-refused-issue-solved

Nothing helped. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by an OpenShift bug - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=984867